# SQL finding most popular books

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, subquery

I have Books table

```
BookID BookName
 1       BookA
 2       BookB
 3       BookC
```

Member table

```
MemberID MemberName
 1          MemberA
 2          MemberB
```

Borrow Table

```
MemberID BookID
 1         1
 1         2
 2         1
 2         2
```

I want to find out five popular book by Memeber A

I tried the following query

```
SELECT        TOP (5) Book.BookTitle, COUNT(*) AS Count, Member_1.MemberName
FROM            Book INNER JOIN
                         Borrow ON Book.BookID = Borrow.BookID INNER JOIN
                         Member ON Borrow.MemberID = Member.MemberID INNER JOIN
                         Member AS Member_1 ON Borrow.MemberID = Member_1.MemberID
                         where Member.MemberName='A'
GROUP BY Book.BookTitle, Member_1.MemberName
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

But this is not giving me the actual result.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You tagged your question MySQL, but the code won't run in MySQL.  I'm confused.

Comment: How is the result different from what you expect? And why do you join the borrowing member twice? And what do you call popular book by a member? You mean they borrow the same book more than once and you rank the books by how often the member borrowed them?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have too many joins:

```
SELECT TOP (5) b.BookTitle, COUNT(*) AS Count, m.MemberName
FROM Book b INNER JOIN
     Borrow bo
     ON bo.BookID = b.BookID INNER JOIN
     Member m
     ON bo.MemberID = m.MemberID 
WHERE m.MemberName = 'A'
GROUP BY b.BookTitle, m.MemberName
ORDER BY Count DESC;
```

Note:  This syntax is usually associated with SQL Server and does not work in MySQL.  In MySQL, you would use `LIMIT 5` rather then `SELECT TOP (5)`.